# Creating multiple artifacts with SBT

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I've seen near-variants of this question, but not with answers that have all the useful information.

Using sbt 0.13.13 and sbt-assembly 0.14.3, and a multi-project build.sbt based on http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Multi-Project.html like this:

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  version := "2.3.0",
  scalaVersion := "2.10.6"
)

lazy val config_jar = (project in file(".")).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(
    name := "myapp-config",
    test in assembly := {},
    assemblyJarName in assembly := "myapp-config.jar",
    includeFilter in Compile := "myapp.conf"
  )

lazy val build_jar = (project in file(".")).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(
    name := "myapp",
    excludeFilter in Compile := "myapp.conf",
    libraryDependencies += ...
  )
```

Is this enough configuration to be able to build two separate jars? What exactly are the full sbt commands to build each
or both from the command line? The command `sbt projects` only shows build_jar, so something's missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few comments:

- Your projects need to point to different paths. Currently both point to the root (`file(".")`) directory.
- Assembly will be available for both projects, so you can call the `assembly` command from each one.
- Why use Scala 2.10? At the very least (if you are say on mixed Scala/Java project and stack on Java 7), use Scala 2.11.8.
- If you want one project to rule them all, you need to have an aggregation project. Calling `assembly` from root will can `assembly` in each of the two other projects (thus creating your two jars).

So I would write:

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  version := "2.3.0",
  scalaVersion := "2.10.6"
)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).aggregate(config_jar, build_jar)   

lazy val config_jar = (project in file("config")).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(
    name := "myapp-config",
    test in assembly := {},
    assemblyJarName in assembly := "myapp-config.jar",
    includeFilter in Compile := "myapp.conf"
  )

lazy val build_jar = (project in file("build")).
  dependsOn(config_jar).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(
    name := "myapp",
    assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := { file =>
        if(file.startsWith("config\\")) MergeStrategy.discard else MergeStrategy.defaultMergeStrategy(file)
    },
    libraryDependencies += ...
  )
```

Comment: Scala 2.10 - I'd like to use the latest and greatest. This build is for a Spark app running on Azure. As near as I've been able to tell, their cloud is constrained to Spark 1.6.3, Scala 2.10. It's on my list to get upgraded when possible.

Comment: The project itself is currently single-project. I was hoping to find a way to build two artifacts from the existing single project. I haven't investigated breaking it in two projects to accomplish this, but will if that's the only way to go about it.

Comment: I thought that you might have a Spark constrained and stayed in 2.10. As for the 2 sub-projects, I think thats the best solution for what you need to do.

Comment: This comes pretty close, except that build_jar requires dependsOn(config_jar) in order for all of its tests to run. As a consequence, the files from config_jar are included in build_jar, even though excludeFilter is specified to filter them out.

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39371112/sbt-multi-project-merge-strategy-and-build-sbt-structure-when-using-assembly I learned that I could use the config jar but exclude its contents from the fat jar. I'll update your example to demonstrate, and you can keep or not as you see fit.

Comment: Cool. Thank you for your help. :)